# Fetching Standard Meteorological Week from pandas dataframe date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe which is having long term data,

```
        point_id     issue_date  latitude   longitude   rainfall    
0           1.0      2020-01-01    6.5          66.50      NaN      
1           2.0      2020-01-02    6.5          66.75      NaN       

... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...


6373888   17414.0    2020-12-30   38.5          99.75      NaN       
6373889   17415.0    2020-12-31   38.5          100.00     NaN  


6373890 rows × 5 columns
```

I want to extract the [Standard Meteorological Week](http://www.icar-crida.res.in:8080/naip/downloads/Standard%20Week%20Chart.pdf) from its issue_date  column, as
given in this figure.

[image: figure]

I have tried in 2 ways.

1st

```
lulc_gdf['smw'] = lulc_gdf['issue_date'].astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.strftime('%V')
```

2nd

```
lulc_gdf['iso'] = lulc_gdf['issue_date'].astype('datetime64[ns]').dt.isocalendar().week
```

The output in both cases is same

```
        point_id     issue_date  latitude   longitude   rainfall    smw   iso
0           1.0      2020-01-01    6.5          66.50      NaN       01    1
1           2.0      2020-01-02    6.5          66.75      NaN       01    1

... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...


6373888   17414.0    2020-12-30   38.5          99.75      NaN       53   53
6373889   17415.0    2020-12-31   38.5          100.00     NaN       53   53


6373890 rows × 7 columns
```

The issue is that the week starts here by taking reference of Sunday or Monday as the starting day of week, irrespective of year.

Like here in case of year 2020 the day on 1st January is Wednesday (not Monday),
so the 1st week is of 5 days only i.e (Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat & Sunday).

```
            year    week    day    issue_date
0           2020      1      3     2020-01-01
1           2020      1      4     2020-01-02
2           2020      1      5     2020-01-03
3           2020      1      6     2020-01-04
... ... ... ...

6373889     2020      53     4     2020-12-31
```

But in the case of **Standard Meteorological Weeks**,
I want output as:
**for every year**

```
1st week should always be from - 1st January to 07th January
2nd week from -                  8th January to 14th January 
3rd week from -                  15th January to 21st January 
------------------------------- and so on
```

irrespective of the starting day of year (Sunday, monday etc).

How to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'issue_date': pd.date_range('2000-01-01','2000-12-31')})
    
#inspire https://stackoverflow.com/a/61592907/2901002
normal_year = np.append(np.arange(363) // 7 + 1, np.repeat(52, 5))
leap_year  = np.concatenate((normal_year[:59], [9], normal_year[59:366]))
days = df['issue_date'].dt.dayofyear

df['smw'] = np.where(df['issue_date'].dt.is_leap_year, 
                     leap_year[days - 1], 
                     normal_year[days - 1])
print (df[df['smw'] == 9])
   issue_date  smw
56 2000-02-26    9
57 2000-02-27    9
58 2000-02-28    9
59 2000-02-29    9
60 2000-03-01    9
61 2000-03-02    9
62 2000-03-03    9
63 2000-03-04    9
```

**Performance**:

```
#11323 rows
df  = pd.DataFrame({'issue_date': pd.date_range('2000-01-01','2030-12-31')})


In [6]: %%timeit
   ...: normal_year = np.append(np.arange(363) // 7 + 1, np.repeat(52, 5))
   ...: leap_year  = np.concatenate((normal_year[:59], [9], normal_year[59:366]))
   ...: days = df['issue_date'].dt.dayofyear
   ...: 
   ...: df['smw'] = np.where(df['issue_date'].dt.is_leap_year,  leap_year[days - 1],  normal_year[days - 1])
   ...: 
3.51 ms ± 154 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [7]: %%timeit
   ...: df['smw1'] = get_smw(df['issue_date'])
   ...: 
17.2 ms ± 312 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

```
#51500 rows
df  = pd.DataFrame({'issue_date': pd.date_range('1900-01-01','2040-12-31')})


In [9]: %%timeit
   ...: normal_year = np.append(np.arange(363) // 7 + 1, np.repeat(52, 5))
   ...: leap_year  = np.concatenate((normal_year[:59], [9], normal_year[59:366]))
   ...: days = df['issue_date'].dt.dayofyear
   ...: 
   ...: df['smw'] = np.where(df['issue_date'].dt.is_leap_year,  leap_year[days - 1],  normal_year[days - 1])
   ...: 
   ...: 
11.9 ms ± 1.47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [10]: %%timeit
    ...: df['smw1'] = get_smw(df['issue_date'])
    ...: 
    ...: 
64.3 ms ± 483 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: @AbhilashSinghChauhan - Ya, you are welcome! If in future performance is important, better is use this solution like another.

Comment: Yes, I just checked, this solution yields results faster than the other one.

Comment: @AbhilashSinghChauhan - Not possible, only one.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom function to calculate the `Standard Meteorological Weeks`.

Normal calculation is by taking the  difference in number of days from 1st January of the same year, then divide by 7 and add 1.

Special adjustment for leap year on Week No. 9 to have 8 days and also special adjustment for the last week of the year to have 8 days:

```
import numpy as np

# convert to datetime format if not already in datetime
df['issue_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['issue_date'])

def get_smw(date_s):
    # get day-of-the-year minus 1 in range [0..364/365] for division by 7
    days_diff = date_s.dt.dayofyear - 1

    # adjust for leap year on Week No. 9 to have 8 days:   (minus one day for 29 Feb onwards in the same year)
    leap_adj = date_s.dt.is_leap_year & (date_s > pd.to_datetime(date_s.dt.year.astype(str) + '-02-28'))
    days_diff = np.where(leap_adj, days_diff - 1, days_diff)

    # adjust for the last week of the year to have 8 days: 
    # Make the value for 31 Dec to 363 instead of 364 to keep it in the same week of 24 Dec)
    days_diff = np.clip(days_diff, 0, 363)

    smw = days_diff // 7 + 1
    return smw

df['smw'] = get_smw(df['issue_date'])
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

         point_id issue_date  latitude  longitude  rainfall  smw
0             1.0 2020-01-01       6.5      66.50       NaN    1
1             2.0 2020-01-02       6.5      66.75       NaN    1
2             3.0 2020-01-03       6.5      66.75       NaN    1
3             4.0 2020-01-04       6.5      66.75       NaN    1
4             5.0 2020-01-05       6.5      66.75       NaN    1
5             6.0 2020-01-06       6.5      66.75       NaN    1
6             7.0 2020-01-07       6.5      66.75       NaN    1
7             8.0 2020-01-08       6.5      66.75       NaN    2
8             9.0 2020-01-09       6.5      66.75       NaN    2
40           40.0 2020-02-26       6.5      66.75       NaN    9
41           41.0 2020-03-04       6.5      66.75       NaN    9
42           42.0 2020-03-05       6.5      66.75       NaN   10
43           43.0 2020-03-12       6.5      66.75       NaN   11
6373880   17414.0 2020-12-23      38.5      99.75       NaN   51
6373881   17414.0 2020-12-24      38.5      99.75       NaN   52
6373888   17414.0 2020-12-30      38.5      99.75       NaN   52
6373889   17415.0 2020-12-31      38.5     100.00       NaN   52
7000040      40.0 2021-02-26       6.5      66.75       NaN    9
7000041      41.0 2021-03-04       6.5      66.75       NaN    9
7000042      42.0 2021-03-05       6.5      66.75       NaN   10
7000042      43.0 2021-03-12       6.5      66.75       NaN   11
7373880   17414.0 2021-12-23      38.5      99.75       NaN   51
7373881   17414.0 2021-12-24      38.5      99.75       NaN   52
7373888   17414.0 2021-12-30      38.5      99.75       NaN   52
7373889   17415.0 2021-12-31      38.5     100.00       NaN   52
```

Comment: Yes @jezrael, Sorry, I totally forgot that. 
    
    for testing leap year 
    leap_test=int(df['issue_date'].dt.year)%4
    if leap_test==0:
        days_to_add=2
    else:
        days_to_add=1 
    
    df['smw'] = (df['issue_date'] - pd.to_datetime(df['issue_date'].dt.year.astype(str) + '-01-01')).dt.days // 7 + int(days_to_add)    
    
    And adding 2 will shift all days, 
    what could be the possible solution in that case?

Comment: Okay, but now it is showing the message "You last voted on this answer 15 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited."

Comment: Okay, Thanks @jazreal

Comment: @AbhilashSinghChauhan  Let me fix it soon!  Currently engaged in some task.  Will surely come back.

Comment: @AbhilashSinghChauhan  See my edit above.  May not be best optimized but it should work.

Comment: @AbhilashSinghChauhan  Completed fine-tuning to optimize the codes.  Please take a look :-)